# Better to use each and check for type vs where to filter for the type in ActiveRecord Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Wondering if say events is an ActiveRecord Relation that this...

```
events.each do |e|
    next unless e.game?
    ....
```

is worse than this...

```
es = events.where(event_type: "game")
es.each do |e|
    ....
```

I was thinking that filtering via SQL may be faster than iterating over each but not sure if looping over each is no different in performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each is much slower. You should always prioritize ActiveRecord method/queries over vanilla Ruby.

```
es = events.where(event_type: "game")
es.find_each do |e|
    ....
```

`events.where(...)` will return an ActiveRecord relation. Because of that you can use `find_each`. The docs suggest not using `find_each` on small collections, but I like to plan for scalability

**EDIT:** If you have any limit or offset, `find_each` will ignore the limit and use the default `find_in_batches` which overwrites the limit to be 1000.

Comment: ah i see `find_each` is good for batching. thanks for pointing that out! you used the where though - would you consider in the examples I gave for this to be the better option?

Comment: I would use the `where` and then the `find_each`. `Array#each` is very slow. You should use ActiveRecord over plain Ruby whenever you can

Comment: Yeah I understand...wanted to confirm on where but will definitely be using find_each as well